# How can I speed up my Rcpp code, which only carries out simple operations?

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a matrix and computes a value for every pair of columns. The matrix always has 2000 rows, but can potentially have a very large number of columns (up to 100,000 or so). The R code I started with is as follows:

```
x_dist <- data.frame(array(0,dim=c(ncol(x),ncol(x))))
cs <- colSums(x)
for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  p_i <- x[,i]
  for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    p_j <- x[,j]
    s <- p_i+p_j
    fac <- cs[i]/(cs[i]+cs[j])
    N1 <- fac*s
    N2 <- (1-fac)*s
    d1 <- (p_i+1)/(N1+1)
    d2 <- (p_j+1)/(N2+1)
    x_dist[i,j] <- sum(N1+N2-N1*d1-N2*d2+p_i*log(d1)+p_j*log(d2))
  }
}
```

This function is quite slow. When there are only 400 columns in the matrix `x`, it takes about 32 seconds, and obviously grows quadratically in the number of columns.

Since I've heard Rcpp is good for speeding up for loops and matrix operations, I decided to give that a try. I am completely new to it, but ended up putting together the following function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix wdist(NumericMatrix x) {
    int nrow = x.nrow(),ncol=x.ncol();
    NumericMatrix m = no_init_matrix(ncol,ncol);
    NumericVector v1 = no_init_vector(nrow);
    NumericVector v2 = no_init_vector(nrow);
    NumericVector s = no_init_vector(nrow);
    NumericVector N1 = no_init_vector(nrow);
    NumericVector N2 = no_init_vector(nrow);
    NumericVector d1 = no_init_vector(nrow);
    NumericVector d2 = no_init_vector(nrow);
    for(int i=0; i<ncol; ++i){
      v1 = x(_,i);
      for(int j=0; j<i; ++j){
        v2 = x(_,j);
        s = v1+v2;
        N1 = sum(v1)*s/(sum(v1)+sum(v2));
        N2 = s-N1;
        d1 = (v1+1)/(N1+1);
        d2 = (v2+1)/(N2+1);
        m(i,j) = sum(N1+N2-N1*d1-N2*d2+v1*log(d1)+v2*log(d2));
      }
    }
    return m;
}
```

This certainly makes a big difference. Now with 400 columns, this takes about 8 seconds. I am pleased by the improvement, but this is still intractably slow for my current test case of interest, which is 32,000 columns. I feel like I am doing some relatively simple operations, so it's confusing to me why my code is still this slow. I've tried to do some reading on writing efficient Rcpp code, but haven't found anything that helps address my issue. Please let me know if there is anything I'm doing wrong or any improvements I can look into to make my code faster (or even the R code itself, if that can be made faster than the Rcpp code!)

---

Some example data could be:

```
set.seed(121220) 
x <- array(rpois(2000*400,3),dim=c(2000,400))
```

Comment: Izzy, mind sharing some simulated data being used in the function? e.g. an `x` matrix?

Comment: Sure! The actual data cannot be shared, but I can replicate the same timing issues on something like this:

set.seed(121220)
x <- array(rpois(2000*400,3),dim=c(2000,400))

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see if the Rcpp part works for you

Answer (score 3):

I refactored your base R code and hope it could speed up somewhat

```
f <- function(...) {
  p <- x[, t(...)]
  N <- matrix(rowSums(p), ncol = 1) %*% colSums(p) / sum(p)
  d <- (p + 1) / (N + 1)
  sum(N - N * d + p * log(d))
}
x_dist <- diag(0, ncol(x))
x_dist[lower.tri(x_dist)] <- combn(ncol(x), 2, FUN = f)
x_dist <- pmax(x_dist, t(x_dist))
```

---

To speed up your Rcpp code, you can try the following nested `for` loops after initializing your matrix `m` as a all-zero matrix:

```
    for(int i=0; i<ncol-1; ++i){
      v1 = x(_,i);
      for(int j=i+1; j<ncol; ++j){
        v2 = x(_,j);
        s = v1+v2;
        N1 = sum(v1)*s/sum(s);
        N2 = s-N1;
        d1 = (v1+1)/(N1+1);
        d2 = (v2+1)/(N2+1);
        val = sum(N1+N2-N1*d1-N2*d2+v1*log(d1)+v2*log(d2));
        m(i,j) = val;
        m(j,i) = val;
      }
    }
```

which applies the property that the matrix is symmetry and thus reduce computational complexity by half.

Comment: Thank you so much! That does reduce the time down from roughly 30 seconds on a 2000 x 400 case to 20 seconds. Unfortunately I think it would still be a little too slow for my cases with more columns, but it is a really nice and compact version of my original code!

Comment: @Izzy, If you think this answer is helpful, you should give is an up-vote. See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: perhaps too trivial to worry about it, but `sum(v1)` occurs twice.  Could save a tiny bit by storing an intermediate value. I wonder about the speed of the `x(_,i)` accessor: is there a faster way to extract a column?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, that's a good point to speed up a bit if we use `sum(s)` instead of `sum(v1) + sum(v2)`, which avoids twice use of `sum(v1)`. I have no clue about the faster way than `x(_,i)`